# ClientProtocolException thrown when using ThreadSafeClientConnManager to execute a http post

Tags: android, http

```
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    ConnManagerParams.setMaxConnectionsPerRoute(params, new ConnPerRouteBean(100));
    ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 100);
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, false);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT); 
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, REQUEST_TIMEOUT);

    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), PORT));

    ThreadSafeClientConnManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);

    HttpClientParams.setCookiePolicy(client.getParams(), CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
```

When my app waits for several seconds, the next post will be failed because of the ClientProtocolException.
By wireshark, I find that android also use the previous tcp socket to execute the post, but  that socket is ended with a FIN from the server. And the next several posts will succeed because a new socket establish.
is there anyone know how to solve the problem??

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Try adding this line :

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

before you make the connection. Might solve your problem.